# index.html is added to our route instead of id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, google-search-console, internal-server-error

Recently, we've understood that Googlebot has faced 593 server errors in our website. After looking at the links, we understood that instead of id in our route, "index.html" is added.

These is the routes of our site:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "NewsView",
            url: "news/{year}/{mounth}/{title}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "NewsView" }
        );
```

We have generated the links as below:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("/news/2016/01/this-is-the-title/14747">@item.Title</a>
```

This is our website's URL, of course as a sample:

```
http://www.ourwebsite.com/news/2016/01/this-is-the-title/14747
```

And this is the URL that Googlebot has faced:

```
http://www.ourwebsite.com/news/2016/01/this-is-the-title/index.html
```

In addition, in the "Linked from" tab of Google webmaster, there is the correct URL, which means that the corrupted URL has been linked from the same page with correct URL.

Also, we are using Microsoft URL Rewrite extension, which we have checked and has no rule for this.

Any Help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Googlebot has most likely found a link to your site on an *external* web site (somewhere out in the wild) that has this URL on it. This has nothing at all to do with the routing of your web site. If you want that link to go somewhere, you could make a URL rewrite rule to do a 301 redirect to another place on your site, but if there is no ID you have to decide exactly where to direct the traffic coming in on that URL.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Thanks for your answer. Actually, it is 4 years that the link has been like this and it used to work. After our latest publish it has faced this issue. Our only change was that we have added a route to this page and removed the year and month part, along with the previous route. Now, we have removed the additional route but again we are facing this issue. Something that is really odd is that why it changes "id" with "index.html".